# WP_Query tax_query problem

Tags: wp-query, tax-query

When I call WP_Query with tax query or category__in, I get posts only from first category in array of requested categories.

```
$query = new WP_Query(
    array(
        "tax_query" => array(
            array(
                "taxonomy" => "category",
                "field" => "term_id",
                "terms" => array(1, 2, 3)
            )
        ),
        "posts_per_page" => -1
    )
);
```

Here is sql query from $query->request:

```
SELECT wp_posts.*
FROM wp_posts
INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id)
INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships AS tt1 ON (wp_posts.ID = tt1.object_id)
INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships AS tt2 ON (wp_posts.ID = tt2.object_id)
WHERE 1=1
  AND (wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id IN (1,
                                                  2,
                                                  3)
       AND tt1.term_taxonomy_id IN (1)
       AND tt2.term_taxonomy_id IN (1))
  AND wp_posts.post_type = 'post'
  AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish'
       OR wp_posts.post_status = 'future'
       OR wp_posts.post_status = 'draft'
       OR wp_posts.post_status = 'pending'
       OR wp_posts.post_status = 'private')
GROUP BY wp_posts.ID
ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC
```

Results list only posts in category 1.
What is wrong with my query?

Comment: What happens if you use `'id'` instead of `'term_id'` for `'field'`?

Comment: I get same results with 'id'.

Comment: Do they happen to be posts that are in *all three* categories?

Comment: I have several posts, one in all categories one in 1 (uncategorized) and few more in 2 and 3. Result is correct but only gives post in first category. If I set categories to (2, 3, 1) it will return only posts with category 2.

Comment: Also sql `AND tt1.term_taxonomy_id IN (1)` 1 changes to first in "terms" array.

Answer (score 2):

Found problem. I replaced:

```
$posts = $query->get_posts();
```

with:

```
$posts = array();
if ($query->have_posts()){
  while ($query->have_posts()){
    $query->next_post();
    array_push($posts, $query->post);
  }
}
```

And everything is working now.